# Issue when adding new top menu using admin panel

Tags: magento2

I created a CMS page from the adminpanel.

[image]

After that i created a CMS block using the admin panel.
Both worked fine.
Then i created a new Category and inside the category form i added the previous generated CMS Block in the "Add CMS Block" Dropdown. In "Display Mode" i selected "Static block only".

The static Block and the Top menu is created like expected, but the Category Title is displayed below of the CMS Block. I want to show the Category Title above the CMS Block.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Provide more information about in details or provide the screenshot or video of the issue which you are facing.

Comment: When i was created new top menu.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot, this information is not enough. If you want to display category in the top navigation menu then there is a feature call displaying menu at category edit page in the backend, once you enable, it will display in the frontend top navigation.

Comment: i've edited the post, now its more understandable and the information is far enough now. The issue is that the category title is displayed below the cms block instead of above.

Comment: yes right . How do that?

Comment: in luma and blank design this is not the case. So you may have something changed at the layout or the templates inside a module or a custom theme, that the category title is displayed below the cms block. But i am not that common with the Magento2 frontend to help you much further.

Answer (score 0):

Please search catalog_category_view.xml or create a new file:

`app/design/frontend/Package/theme` in that create a file with name `catalog_category_view.xml` at below location

> `app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/layout`

And put this code there in the file `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <move element="columns.top" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note: Please run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Please let me know if you still facing the same issue.

Comment: thank you so for the solution its work me

Comment: I have one more issue, I want add default Contact Us into the Top menu but Not Working? Anyone idea how to configuration?

Comment: This is the answer to your question then, Please accept this as an answer so it will help others.

Comment: its working for me. Thanks for the solutions

Comment: Please accept this as solution if it is working for you.